# How to replace elements in specified columns of a matrix?

Tags: r

I have a large matrix (500-row by 30000-column) of zeros and ones.  To this, I have appended row 501 containing values between 0 and 1.  If the value in row 501 is > 0.5 for column x, I want to replace all zeros with ones and all ones with zeros in that column.  I have implemented the code below:

```
for(x in 1:30000){
  if (matrix[501,x] > 0.5){
    for(y in 1:500){
      matrix[matrix[y,x]==1] <- 0
      matrix[matrix[y,x]==0] <- 1
    }
  }
}
matrix
```

This code runs continuously, and I've gone as long as 2 hours before stopping it, so I don't have an error message to report.  How can I clean this up? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are using O(n^2) algorithm, in addition, loop is very slow in r. Read this article http://bigocheatsheet.com/. This will give you insight how to rewrite your code

Comment: Note also that your first replacement line will be undone by your second replacement line.

Comment: Thank you lmo and Kppatel. Hadn't thought that maybe I'm stuck in a loop of replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flip 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0 together by using `x <- 1 - x`.

So you would have

```
toFlip <- matrix[501,] > 0.5
matrix[1:500, toFlip] <- 1 - matrix[1:500,toFlip]
```

Comment: Also `!matrix[1:500,toFlip]` works (`!x` flips 0 to 1 and vice versa).

Comment: I guess it depends if you want a number or a boolean.